# Correct use of str_replace_all within a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to use str_replace_all within a user-defined function in r to replace all instances of the letter 'T' in a column in a data frame with a space. The function also removes the last letter from each string.

#### Desired output

For the data below, this would convert the first table into the second when the column `df$code` is passed through:

```
id    code
1     STWX
2     STVX
3     RTUX

id    code
1     S W
2     S V
3     R U
```

#### Previous attempts

I've tried using the following:

```
str_convert <- function(x) {
str_replace_all(x, 'T', ' ')
substr(x,1,nchar(x)-1)
}
```

However, the output I get doesn't remove the 'T', so the final output looks like this:

```
id    code
1     STW
2     STV
3     RTU
```

Am I making an obvious mistake? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is because you are not saving the results of `str_replace` and then remove the last char from that. You are doing two different operations on the original string. The function returns the latest one, in your case the `substr(...)`

Comment: You need `x <- str_replace_all(x, 'T', ' ')` in the first row of your function's body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
str_convert <- function(x) {
   r <- str_replace_all(x, 'T', ' ')
   r <- substr(r,1,nchar(r)-1)
 return(r)
   }

 df1 %>% 
   mutate(res = str_convert(code))
  id code res
1  1 STWX S W
2  2 STVX S V
3  3 RTUX R U
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I suppose I forgot to assign things to proper outputs. Clearly a lot more to learn in R...

Answer (score 1):

and the tidyverse solution:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3, code = c("STWX", "STVX", "RTUX"))

str_convert <- function(x) {
  str_replace_all(x, 'T', ' ') %>%
  str_sub(1, -2)
}

df %>% 
   mutate(code = str_convert(code))
  id code code
1  1 STWX S W
2  2 STVX S V
3  3 RTUX R U
```

This forwards the output from str_replace_all as the first argument of str_sub, of which the result is subsequently returned by the function. str_sub can also have a negative stop value (counting back from the end), which is convenient here.